# How to algebraically determine locus of points of $|z|=|z-2|$?

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

How would I algebraically determine the locus of points in the $z$-plane that satisfy the equation $|z|=|z-2|$?

Comment: What do you think? What approaches have you considered, and how far did you get with them?

Comment: Let $z=x+iy$, so $x^2+y^2=(x-2)^2+y^2$, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put $z=a+\iota b$

$$|z|=|z-2|$$
$$|a+\iota b|=|a+\iota b-2|$$
$$|a+\iota b|=|a-2+\iota b|$$
$$a^2+b^2=(a-2)^2+b^2$$
$$a^2+b^2=a^2+4-4a+b^2$$
$$4=4a$$
gives us $$a=1$$
means equation of the locus is $$Re(z)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\,|z|^2 = |z-2|^2 \iff z \bar z = (z-2)(\bar z - 2) \iff 2z + 2\bar z = 4 \iff \operatorname{Re}(z)=1\,$.

Of course, it's more direct to note that geometrically the locus is the pependicular bisector of the segment between $0$ and $2$.

Comment: Why would you call this a hint? It's practically a full solution.

Comment: @Arthur There still are a few blanks left to fill-in. It would not get a great grade if copy-pasted as a homework answer.

Comment: Yes, there are some small cracks left over to fill in, but I personally think that makes this into a brief answer, not a hint. You take away all the real problem solving and leave a few minor calculations. Which is perfectly fine, but it doesn't deserve to be called a hint on my opinion.

Comment: @Arthur `doesn't deserve to be called a hint` Maybe, yet that's my warning shot to the OP that they have some work left to do ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The equation says it,

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}.$$

Squaring won't introduce new solutions as both members are positive and the arguments of the square roots are positive, hence after simplification

$$0=4-4x.$$

---

From the equation,

$$z=(z-2)e^{i\theta}$$ and

$$z=-\frac{2e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}=-\frac{2e^{i\theta}(1-e^{-i\theta})}{(1-e^{i\theta})(1-e^{-i\theta})}=\frac{2-2e^{i\theta}}{2-2\Re(e^{i\theta})}$$ which has the real part $1$.